# 404 not found error when trying to download Hadoop

Tags: wget, hadoop

I entered the command to download hadoop, but it tells me that there's no connection and `404 not found`.

[image]
<sup>**HTTP request transmitted, waiting for response… 404 not found**</sup>

Comment: It's most likely that your URL is not valid and not present on the Apache servers.  This isn't something *we* can solve.  Go to the Hadoop website and find the latest download links to download and install Hadoop